# How do I directly cast a numpy array from a csv file using np.genfromtxt?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I am attempting to generate a numpy array directly from the csv file. I read up online that you can do this using the np.genfromtxt function of the module. I attempted this but all my values were nan. The dataset is from kaggle about nyc taxis.

```
import numpy as np

taxi = np.genfromtxt("nyc_taxis.csv", delimiter=";", skip_header=1)

print(taxi)
```

The output is :

array([nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan])

I am trying to practice efficiency and use as few lines of code in this project as possible.

I have also attempted to use the np.loadtxt() function but it returned this error

```
taxi = np.loadtxt("nyc_taxis.csv", delimiter=";", dtype =np.float, skiprows=1)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-8c3c6082acc0> in <module>
----> 1 taxi = np.loadtxt("nyc_taxis.csv", delimiter=";", dtype =np.float, skiprows=1)
      2 
      3 taxi

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows)
   1157         # converting the data
   1158         X = None
-> 1159         for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
   1160             if X is None:
   1161                 X = np.array(x, dtype)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in read_data(chunk_size)
   1085 
   1086             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1087             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1088 
   1089             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1085 
   1086             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1087             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1088 
   1089             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in floatconv(x)
    792         if '0x' in x:
    793             return float.fromhex(x)
--> 794         return float(x)
    795 
    796     typ = dtype.type

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2016,1,1,5,0,2,4,21.00,2037,52.00,0.80,5.54,11.65,69.99,1'
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: The sample shown in the error message shows a comma being used as a delimiter.  Why are you using `delimiter=';'`?  Try `delimiter=','`.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you can show at least the first few lines of the input file in the question.

Comment: The default `dtype` for `genfromtxt` is `float`.  If the csv element is not a valid number, it puts `np.nan` in that slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to set delimiter=',', as your file is comma separated.
- You have to set dype for string columns manually, otherwise it becomes nan (Only columns specified its dtype is loaded, so I set all columns' dtype).

I downloaded test.csv from [Kaggle: New York City Taxi Trip Duration](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nyc-taxi-trip-duration/data):
[image]

nyc.py

```
import numpy as np
dtype=[
    ('id', 'S16'),
    ('vender_id', np.uint8),
    ('pickup_datetime', 'S16'),
    ('passenger_count', np.uint8),
    ('pickup_longitude', np.float32),
    ('pickup_latitude', np.float32),
    ('dropoff_longitude', np.float32),
    ('dropoff_latitude', np.float32),
    ('store_and_fwd_flag', 'S8'),
]
csv = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=dtype)
print(csv[:3])
```

, where 'S8' means string 8 bytes, outputs

```
❯ python nyc.py
[(b'id3004672', 1, b'2016-06-30 23:59', 1, -73.98813, 40.73203 , -73.99017, 40.75668 , b'N')
 (b'id3505355', 1, b'2016-06-30 23:59', 1, -73.9642 , 40.679993, -73.95981, 40.655403, b'N')
 (b'id1217141', 1, b'2016-06-30 23:59', 1, -73.99744, 40.737583, -73.98616, 40.729523, b'N')]
```

P.S. I recommend pandas.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Thank you Naoki. I appreicate the detailed explanation. Very thankful you took the time. One question I have is if you had to fill in the type list of tuples manually? As in did you open the csv file first, then copy the headers to the list and assign each header the desired dtype?

Comment: yeah, I had to check in other spreadsheet software. It seems hard to do it only with numpy (numpy is mainly for handling numeric data).

Comment: With `dtype=None` and `names=True`, `genfromtxt` can deduce column names and dtype from the file.

Comment: So i ran the code using the modification suggested by hpaulj and tried to check the shape of the array using taxi.shape and it returned the correct number of rows but showed nothing for the columns in the returned tuple`

taxi.shape

out ; (89560,)

Any clue why this could be happening?